# string to integer (implement atoi)

Tags: c, strings, interview-questions

> Implement atoi to convert a string to an integer.
>
> Requirements for atoi: The function first discards as many whitespace
>   characters as necessary until the first non-whitespace character is
>   found. Then, starting from this character, takes an optional initial
>   plus or minus sign followed by as many numerical digits as possible,
>   and interprets them as a numerical value.
>
> The string can contain additional characters after those that form the
>   integral number, which are ignored and have no effect on the behavior
>   of this function.
>
> If the first sequence of non-whitespace characters in str is not a
>   valid integral number, or if no such sequence exists because either
>   str is empty or it contains only whitespace characters, no conversion
>   is performed.
>
> If no valid conversion could be performed, a zero value is returned.
>   If the correct value is out of the range of representable values,
>   INT_MAX (2147483647) or INT_MIN (-2147483648) is returned.

The following is my code:

```
int atoi(const char *str) {
    int sign = 1;
    long long i = 0, j = 0;

    while ((*str) != '\0' && isspace(*str)) {
        ++str;
    }

    if (((*str)!='\0') && ((*str) == '+' || (*str) == '-')) {
        if ((*str) == '-') {
            sign = -1;
        }
        ++str;
    }

    if (((*str) != '\0') && (!isdigit(*str))) {
        return 0;
    }

    while (((*str) != '\0') && (isdigit(*str))) {
        i = i * 10 + (*str - '0');
        j = i * sign;
        cout << j << endl;
        if (j > INT_MAX) {
            return INT_MAX;
        }
        if (j < INT_MIN) {
            return INT_MIN;
        }

        ++str;
    }

    return j;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (((*str) != '\0') && (!isdigit(*str))) {
    return 0;
}
```

You don't need this condition, because of the condition in the while loop afterwards. If that fails the first time `j` with value `0` is returned anyway.

And a minimal (and maybe unnecessary) optimization:

```
if (j >= INT_MAX) {
    return INT_MAX;
}
if (j <= INT_MIN) {
    return INT_MIN;
}
```

Why look for the next character in the string which would only get appended to the number and would increase the value, if the number already has the maximumk/minimum value possible (`INT_MAX`/`INT_MIN`).

Comment: Why look for the next character which only makes the number bigger if you already reached INT_MAX/INT_MIN? Can you explain this sentence more detail. I don't understand.

Comment: @FihopZz, I edited my answer, I hope its understandable now (English is not my native language)

Comment: If the number already has the maximum/minimum value, which is checked by `if (j >= INT_MAX)` and `if (j <= INT_MIN)` in my code, there is no necessary to check the next character. It seems that this is what I do. :-).

Comment: In your code you return if `j > INT_MAX`, but you don't return if `j` is already equal to `INT_MAX`, so better IMO would be returning if `j >= INT_MAX` like I suggested.

Comment: `if (j >= INT_MAX)` tests it too late to prevent undefined behavior of the prior `i = i * 10 + (*str - '0');` on platforms where `INT_MAX == LLONG_MAX`.

Answer (score 4):

You seem to have too many checks for '\0'. They don't add anything. Also too many brackets, but better too many than too few.

Also, is `long long` guaranteed to be bigger than `int`? I don't think it is. Here's another version that doesn't need a bigger representation than that of `int`:

```
int atoi(const char *str)
{
    int n = 0;
    int sign = 1;

    while (isspace(*str)) {
        ++str;
    }
    if (*str == '-') {
        sign = -1;
        ++str;
    } else if (*str == '+') {
        sign = 1;
        ++str;
    }
    while (isdigit(*str)) {
        if (n > INT_MAX/10) { /* EDIT: protect against overflow */
            break;
        }
        n *= 10;
        int ch = *str - '0';

        if (n > INT_MAX - ch) {
            break;
        }
        n += ch;
        ++str;
    }
    if (isdigit(*str)) {
        return sign == 1 ? INT_MAX : INT_MIN;
    }
    return sign * n;
}
```

EDIT: I added a check to prevent overflow of the `n *= 10`

EDIT2: improved to avoid using an unsigned int - it was a hack

Comment: very nice!!!!!!!

Comment: Minor `is...(*str)` is UB when `*str < 0`. Consider `isspace((unsigned char) *str)`, `isdigit((unsigned char) *str)` .

Comment: This code has a novel and functionally correct way to prevent overflow.  Clarity to add: `if (isdigit(*str)) {` is true in 2 conditions: overflow and when forming a non-overflow result of `INT_MIN`. e.g. `atoi("-2147483648")`.

Answer (score 1):

**`is...()` UB**

`is...(c)` can be *undefined behavior* (UB) when `c < 0`.  To prevent, cast to `unsigned char`.

```
// isspace(*str);
isspace((unsigned char) *str);

// isdigit(*str);
isdigit((unsigned char) *str);
```

**Invalid C code**

`cout << j << endl;` is not well defined in C.  I suspect OP is using a non-C compiler.

**Code assumes `long long` wider than `int`**

`if (j > INT_MAX)` is not possible when `INT_MAX == LLONG_MAX`.  Prior `i = i * 10` can readily overflow signed integer math which is UB.

In any case, the approach of needing wider math fails when trying to code `atoll()`.

Better to detect potential overflow using `int` math.  Alternative:

```
int neg_sum = 0;
while (isdigit((unsigned char) *str))) {
  int digit = *str++ - '0';
  if (neg_sum <= INT_MIN/10 && (neg_sum < INT_MIN/10 || digit > -(INT_MIN%10))) {
    neg_sum = INT_MIN; // out of range
    break;
  } 
  neg_sum = neg_sum*10 - digit;
}

if (sign == 1) {
  if (neg_sum < -INT_MAX) {
    return INT_MAX; 
  }
  return -neg_sum; 
}
return neg_sum;
```